# Frequency-dependent behavior of R and L in LTspice

Tags: ac, ltspice, simulation, frequency-response

I have this question that I have been dealing with for quite some time now.

Say I have an electrical machine that I model using lumped parameter (RLC circuit). As we all know, R and L are frequency-dependent (R because of skin and proximity effects, L because of the presence of the magnetic material). I want to simulate the frequency-dependent behavior of the machine in LTspice but .TRANS simulation will not work because, like I have learned here, Laplace function does not exhibit reliable outputs when it is used in .TRANS simulations, whereas, for .ac, it works just fine.

The problem I am having with .ac simulation is that it is generally used to measure the impedance of the system. For my case study, I am more interested in the distribution of the voltages in some nodes of interest, when the machine is supplied with a trapezoidal waveform voltage (or other weirdly shaped voltages with a very wide spectrum). I am trying to analyze my circuit in frequency domain and output the spectrum of all the currents and voltages that I want. Hope I was as clear as possible.

Comment: so is your question how to get .TRANS to work, or how to turn the .ac analysis into time data?

Comment: Well I'd love to have a proposition on how to include frequency dependent parameters in a time domain simulation. I have used passive components that reproduce the same behavior as R(f) and L(f) and run it in .TRANS but the output voltages are of 1e79 amplitude !! idk what I am doing wrong.. So I thought maybe doing an .ac analysis to extract the voltage distribution and apply an ifft would be much more efficient. what do you think?

Comment: But what is the top-line, real-world problem you are trying to solve on electrical machines? Maybe if you start at what you are ultimately trying to uncover, there might be a better way?

Comment: I am trying to extract the voltage distribution within the winding of the machine that is modelled using lumped parameters model, the values of the parameters of the model are of great importance for a good prediction of the voltage distribution. So taking into account their frequency dependent behavior in a time domain simulation is what I am trying to resolve. So I thought maybe run a frequency simulation, get the spectrum of the different voltages at my nodes of interest an apply an ifft to get the time domain voltages. How can I do that in LTspice?

Comment: the frequency dependent behavior of each parameter is computed using FEM, fitted and can be represented with analytical function..

Comment: @Wallflower Your question is a wall of words. Show us equations and, if you please, also a schematic with .tran which fails and doesn't preform what your equations express. No words anymore. Just cold equations. Done with words, I am.

Comment: I don't understand, what's stopping you from trying? All you have to do is just that: run the simulation and then perfom FFT. Running the simulation is done through the toolbar button "run", or through the `Simulate > Run` command in the main menu, and the FFT is either through righ-click in the waveform viewer and then `View > FFT`, or from the main menu (with the waveform window active), same `View > FFT`.

Comment: @a_concerned_citizen The problem is not with trying, but rather how to do it...

Comment: @jonk Analytically if you have a circuit, say a trapezoidal voltage source suppling a resistor. You can analyze the system in frequency domain as in performing an ifft for the input voltage, by taking into account skin effect R(f) = k.sqrt(s) and then compute the current: I(f) = V(f)/R(f). This yields the spectrum of the current on which you can apply an ifft to get the time domain equivalent. In LTspice the .ac analysis only helps compute the impedance of the system not analyze it in FD and get the spectrum of the voltage/current distribution in your system. How can I do that?

Comment: @Wallflower You may be thinking in the wrong direction. You're saying you want an `.AC` analysis, from which you can perform `IFFT`, but an `.AC` analysis is, by definition, a *linear* operation around an operating point, a small signal analysis, i.e. the circuit is linearized prior to simulation. What you (probably) need is the reverse: a `.TRAN` where you feed your trapezoidal voltage to the circuit, and then perform an `FFT` on that, if needed.

Comment: @a concerned citizen  But how can I perform a .TRANS analysis with frequency dependent resistances and inductances?

Comment: @Wallflower You can, which is why I'm not discussing anything further until I see what you've attempted for .tran and why you don't think it works as you think it should. Plus, of course, I want to see your Laplace equations. (and not simple V(f) expressions hand-typed out.) So we wait.

Comment: @jonk I have attempted to use Laplace equation in my .TRANS simulations. My circuit is so complex that the output time domain voltage had weird shapes. I have searched and asked a little in other LTspice forums, where I have learned that the laplace works well in the .ac but not that well (a very unpredictable behavior) in .TRANS simulations. My resistances are of the following expression: R(f) = k*sqrt(s), k depends on the turns that is studied (an electrical machine with 56 turns).

Comment: @Wallflower We will depart from each other, then. Without specific details on your mental processes and attempts, including the math as well as the attempted .TRAN LTspice runs, I'm just not very interested. That's just me, so don't worry about it. If you don't feel like it, that's fine. I'm not pushing. Just letting you know where I'm at and what I care about and don't. Others may certainly feel differently and that might work well for you. But I'm not seeing anything I care to invest my time in, just yet, other than saying "hi" for now. So I think we part company at this point. No foul.

Comment: @jonk, you asked for the laplace equations. I've shared the laplace equations with you... I don't get it. Do you want me to share my netlist with you? I honestly don't think the comment section is for sharing an entire LTspice netlist (for visualization and given the fixed number of characters...)

Comment: @Wallflower I think I've tried enough to communicate. It may be a language issue or just my lack of interest reading words instead of equations. No, you've not shared your Laplace equations with me -- nothing I recognize as such anyway. So let's leave it there. Someone else perhaps understands you better than I do and will be of better use to you.

Comment: @jonk Sorry for the misunderstanding then.

Comment: @Wallflower No need to apologize. You are communicating in ways you feel work for you. I'm just not connecting with that. It doesn't mean someone else can't. It's just that I've asked for what I need and you apparently can't follow that request well. Without any reflection on you or me, it simply means we failed to connect and that I've given up worrying about it. Neither of us have a right to insist upon the other. So it stops. That's all.

Comment: @Wallflower Hey, there.  I suggest reading the last paragraph of the LTspice help section titled "B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources".  It gives some advice on trying to tweak away the time domain errors/artifacts you mentioned you are seeing in your Laplace .TRAN simulation.  Sorry if this comment is not condescending enough to fit in with the rest of them.

Comment: @Ste Kulov, will do. Thank you ! :)